# user privileges ldap scheme

Tags: ldap, users, permissions

I needed to create a user (it's already created) in my LDAP schema and want to give privileges of reading/writing to that user like if they were the admin but just for a specific subtree.

The thing is I added an ACL in `slapd.conf` like this:

```
access to dn.subtree="dc=domain,dc=com,o=isp" by dn="cn=user,dc=domain,dc=com,o=isp" manage by * none
```

When I login into `phpldapadmin` with that user, I can't see anything from the subtree, but get message:

```
o=isp This base entry does not exist. Create it?
```

That entry actually exist so something's not working.

If change the ACL attribute inside `slapd.conf` to this:

```
access to * by dn="cn=user,dc=domain,dc=com,o=isp" manage by * none
```

Then, when I login, I can see all the scheme and subtrees but only want to give privileges for a specific `dn`, not the whole scheme.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found the problem.

I changed the next line inside `/etc/phpladadmin/config.php`:

```
$servers->setValue('server','base',array('dc=domain,dc=com,o=isp'));
```

So now when I login inside phpladadmn I can see the correct subtree schema with the user who has the correct privileges.